# Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Tags: php

Хочу получить ответ с API, получаю вот такую ошибку.
Искал решение - везде пишут, что надо что-то поменять в файле php.ini. Но у меня такого файла нет! Пробовал через `phpinfo()` посмотреть - там тоже не видит его.

Comment: Где код, выполнение которого ошибку даёт?

Comment: Я вызывал функцию file_get_contents() - на ней сыпется. С моим кодом всё в порядке, в качестве аргумента просто передаю туда урлу - с ней тоже всё ок.

Answer (score 0):

1)php.ini — Это конфигурационный файл PHP, который обычно находится

- Windows: рядом с php.exe.
- Linux: в одной из папок: "/etc", "/usr/local/lib" и "/usr/local/php/etc".

2)Вам надо установить true для allow_url_fopen в упомянутом выше конфиге, либо просто использовать [ini_set(string $option, string | int | float | bool | null $value)](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ini-set.php) в своём скрипте:

```php
<?php
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", true);
```

Comment: В том-то и дело, что нет нигде этого php.ini. Ни в одной директории с php.exe, ни в других папках. Есть только php.ini-production и php.ini-development, но там параметр allow_url_fopen включен

Comment: А какая у вас платформа (Windows или Linux) и пробовали ли использовать ini_set?

Comment: И насчёт отсутсвия php.ini, просто переименуйте php.ini-production в php.ini (либо же php.ini-development, если вы хотите настроить его сами :)

Comment: У меня винда. ini_set прописал, но вроде как ничего не изменилось - по крайней мере, файлик так и не появился, и в phpinfo ничего не видит

Comment: Переименовал production-файл, вроде заработало. Спасибо!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста